# ApiPlatform ApiFilter no working when using Custom StateProvider 2024

Tags: api-platform.com, php-8, symfony6

I've seen this question here before but none of the solutions worked and can't understand why.

My Class (Not an Entity)

```
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use App\State\CustomStateProvider;
use DateTimeInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
    #[GetCollection(formats: [
    'jsonld',
    'json',
    'html',
    'csv' => 'text/csv' ], 
    shortName: 'APIS WURTH',
    paginationItemsPerPage: 5,
    description: 'Endpoints de Test para Wurth',
    //filters: ['dossier' => 'exact'],
    filters: [
        'clearence' => 'partial',
        'reference' => 'exact'
    ],
    provider: CustomStateProvider::class
)]
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['clearence'=> 'partial', 'reference' => 'exact'])]
class MyApiDataClass{...}
```

My Provider:

```
class CustomStateProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(private readonly EntityManagerInterface $em, private readonly SerializerInterface $serializer){}
    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): object|array|null
    {
        if ($operation instanceof CollectionOperationInterface) {              
            $all = $this->getDataCollection();
            $data = [];
            foreach ($all as $a) {
                $data[] = $this->serializer->deserialize($a, MyApiDataClass::class, 'json');
            }
            return $data;
        }
        {...}
    }
}
```

All answers i've seen are more than 4 years old and i don't know how to adapt the answers to this.
Filters are working. Here is another working class:

```
#[ORM\Table(name: 'MyTable')]
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ApiResource(
    shortName: 'My Api',
    description: '...',
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(uriTemplate: '/test'),
        new Get(uriTemplate: '/test/{id}'),
    ],
    formats: [
        'jsonld',
        'json',
        'html',
        'jsonhal',
        'csv' => 'text/csv'
    ],
    paginationItemsPerPage: 10
)]
#[ApiFilter(BooleanFilter::class, properties: ['sent'])]
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, strategy: 'exact', properties: ['element'])]
class DocumentsQue {...}
```

This is perfectly working. Is it because this is an Entity? or because the other uses CustomStateProvider? Can't figure it out.

Regular with filters:
[image]

Custom no filters:
[image]

I'm sure i'm missing somthing obvius but i've spend so much time. Anything helps at this point.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of try/error i've found the solution.

```
#[ApiResource(
    shortName: 'APIS TEST',
    description: '...',
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(
            uriTemplate: 'test',
            openapiContext: [
                "parameters" => [
                    [
                        "name" => 'field1',
                        "in" => 'query',
                        "description" => '...',
                        "schema" => [
                            "type" => "string"
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        "name" => 'field2',
                        "in" => 'query',
                        "description" => '...',
                        "schema" => [
                            "type" => "string"
                        ]
                    ]

                ]
            ],
            class: MyApiDataClass::class,
            paginationItemsPerPage: 5,
            description: '...',
        ),
    ],
    formats: [
        'jsonld',
        'json',
        'html',
        'csv' => 'text/csv'],
    paginationItemsPerPage: 5,
    provider: CustomStateProvider::class,
    extraProperties: ['field1', 'field2']
)]
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['field1' => 'partial', 'field2' => 'exact'])]
```

Since ApiFilter doesn't work when using Custom State Providers. Manually configuring openapiContext will do the trick.

Hope i can help anyboy facing the same issue. It was a really simple thing that it took me long enough.

I got the solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369988/how-to-ask-for-additional-get-parameters-in-an-endpoint-of-api-platform-using-sw). znizzardini 's answer.
Cheers!